# Root took over account in 18.04

Tags: login

I had a login loop on one my accounts. The other ones appear to work. When I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> to open the terminal, log into my normal account and type `sudo xstart`, I seem to be logging into root user with my normal home directory. How do I fix this so I can log in properly again?

Second Edit: startx without sudo gives a timeout from Xauthority then gives an xinit server error

First Edit: This is the .xsession-errors

```
dbus-update-activation-environment: systemd --user not found, ignoring --systemd argument
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting DISPLAY=:1
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XAUTHORITY=/home/standard/.Xauthority
localuser:root being added to access control list
dbus-update-activation-environment: systemd --user not found, ignoring --systemd argument
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting GTK_MODULES=gail:atk-bridge
dbus-update-activation-environment: systemd --user not found, ignoring --systemd argument
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting QT_ACCESSIBILITY=1
dbus-update-activation-environment: systemd --user not found, ignoring --systemd argument
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting SUDO_GID=1000
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting MAIL=/var/mail/root
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting USER=root
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting HOME=/home/standard
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting QT4_IM_MODULE=xim
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting GTK_MODULES=gail:atk-bridge
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-mNX4Ha4s9l,guid=624789917a86589ef80a2eef5e389cc7
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting SUDO_UID=1000
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting IM_CONFIG_PHASE=1
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LOGNAME=root
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting GTK_IM_MODULE=ibus
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting TERM=linux
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting USERNAME=root
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting WINDOWPATH=3
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting DISPLAY=:1
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LANG=en_US.UTF-8
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LS_COLORS=rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.zst=01;31:*.tzst=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.wim=01;31:*.swm=01;31:*.dwm=01;31:*.esd=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mjpg=01;35:*.mjpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XAUTHORITY=/home/standard/.Xauthority
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XMODIFIERS=@im=ibus
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting SUDO_COMMAND=/usr/bin/startx
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting SHELL=/bin/bash
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting QT_ACCESSIBILITY=1
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting SUDO_USER=standard
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting GPG_AGENT_INFO=/home/standard/.gnupg/S.gpg-agent:0:1
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting QT_IM_MODULE=ibus
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting PWD=/home/standard
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XDG_DATA_DIRS=/usr/share/gnome:/home/standard/.local/share/flatpak/exports/share:/var/lib/flatpak/exports/share:/usr/local/share:/usr/share
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting CLUTTER_IM_MODULE=xim
```

Comment: What OS/release are you using?

Comment: You started a 2nd X server while the first X server (that you abandoned) was still running. They're fighting overthe same set of resources.

Comment: @waltinator How do I fix that?

Comment: Reboot, `service lightdm stop`, `pkill -9 startx`,

Comment: @waltinator I am able to log in to other users and I am aslo using gdm3.

Comment: Then `service gdm3 stop`. Whichever one you stop, you'll have to stop and restart the other.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it.

`ls -lA` gave the following on "standard":

```
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   38 Feb  4 00:30 .bash_aliases
-rw-------  1 root root  501 Feb  4 00:31 .bash_history
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  220 Feb  4 00:07 .bash_logout
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 3771 Feb  4 00:07 .bashrc
drwx------ 14 root root 4096 Feb  4 00:11 .cache
drwx------ 12 root ....
```

The solution was to run `sudo chown -R standard . && sudo chgrp -R standard .` to recursively change ownership and group to standard. Afterward `ls -lA` looks like

```
-rw-r--r--  1 standard standard   38 Feb  4 00:30 .bash_aliases
-rw-------  1 standard standard  501 Feb  4 00:31 .bash_history
-rw-r--r--  1 standard standard  220 Feb  4 00:07 .bash_logout
-rw-r--r--  1 standard standard 3771 Feb  4 00:07 .bashrc
drwx------ 14 standard ....
```

Now "standard" can log in properly and no longer gives a login loop.
Note: It took way to long to realize that root actually owned everything